# Log to a channel in Microsoft Teams with NLog

Tags: c#, nlog, microsoft-teams

**Objective**

Log the errors to Microsoft Teams with NLog from a console program.

**Issue**

Was able to log to the console, but not to Teams

**Code**

Config:

```xml
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="console"/>
    <target xsi:type="WebService"
         name="microsoft-teams"
         url="https://outlook.office.com/webhook/abcd"
         protocol='JsonPost' 
         encoding='UTF-8' 
         includeBOM='false' >
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name='*' writeTo='microsoft-teams' />
</rules>
```

Logging code:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
public static void Main(string[] args) {

    logger.Error("{'text':'test'}");
    logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message");

}
```

The console target displayed the errors very well. But the Teams channel didn't have log, the `nlog-internal.log` showed

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need at least send some parameters, see example webserver target:

```xml
<target type='WebService'
        name='ws'
        url='http://localhost:1234/logme'
        protocol='HttpPost'
        encoding='UTF-8'   >
    <parameter name='param1' type='System.String' layout='${message}'/> 
    <parameter name='param2' type='System.String' layout='${level}'/>
</target>
```

If this still isn't working, I would recommend checking the call with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: That was the example I followed, how do I use the params? Btw, the call works fine in Fiddler/Postman

Comment: Turned out I named the layout the same name with param1, apparently they are predefined. Now it works! Thank you @Julian

Comment: I was able to send a string via `logger.Fatal("Test");` but can't send the json format like `logger.Fatal(new ComplextType{Text = "test", Title="test title"});` Seems I need this https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1905, but is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a little bit late, but you can try the NLog extension I created.
https://github.com/jedipi/NLog.Targets.MicrosoftTeams

[image: Example Output]